# Is it a good practice to keep one CLLocationManager inside my AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

My app monitors user location, including some background location monitoring.

I had one location manager inside my App Delegate mainly for initial launch location and also for the background updates. Then I had another manager inside my view controller (map) for more specific events and quick reference.

I was wondering if it was a good practice to refactor this into one instance, kept in App Delegate, and refer to it throughout the app using:

```
self.appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[self.appDelegate.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways of doing it, but the app delegate is reasonable. Alternatively you could have a singleton - a static CLLocationManager object exposed through a property - in its own class too.

Comment: Following MVC, your view controller should… control your view.  It should be *told* what data to display, and its logic should all relate to how a user sees and interacts with data.  It should *not* be responsible for getting data, whether from a web server or a CLLocationManager.  So, unless your app is *extremely* simple, the CLLoctionManager belongs neither in your app delegate nor your view controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on what the other commenters have suggested, I also suggest to put it into its own class, like so:

```
// Header
@interface MyLocationManager : NSObject
+ (MyLocationManager *)sharedInstance;
@property (readonly) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end


// Implementation
@implementation MyLocationManager
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _locationManager = /* set up your location manager */;
    }

    return self;
}

+ (MyLocationManager *)sharedInstance
{
    static MyLocationManager *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[MyLocationManager alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
@end
```

Then you can use your `MyLocationManager` anywhere in your app by calling `[MyLocationManager sharedInstance]`.

Comment: I finally refactored my code this weekend and implemented a singleton "LocationController". Brilliant - thanks so much.

Comment: No, Apple put a lot of work into making CLLocationManager work as multiple instances don't undo that with a singleton. Create a different manager for each purpose.

Comment: @malhal: Yes, it's important to use the right tool for the job, absolutely! In some apps you might just have a single purpose for using a location manager and then - imho - it's fine to use a singleton.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be better to have one class to handle the locations, following the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), to keep things [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29):

> In object-oriented programming, the single responsibility principle
>   states that every class should have a single responsibility, and that
>   responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. All its
>   services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

If a convention gets in your way then don't use it.

You want to weigh the cost of keeping that location manager in memory compared to how long it takes to initialize.  If say, each time it started the location manager it took a minute then yes, you would want to keep one instance somewhere convenient, as in the app delegate and access it in other places.  Likewise if the manager was pretty much instant but memory expensive it would usually be better to make and use it only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

`CLLocationManager` was designed to work as multiple instances so create one for each feature in your app. They are all lightweight so don't worry about creating lots of them and they all communicate with one private location client that starts and stops the GPS depending on how many managers there are.

Refactoring it into a single instance is undoing all the hard work Apple did to make it work as multiple instances.